# Add item to listview from another form

Tags: c#, class, variables

I've stomped with a problem I've spent some hours trying to solve, with my very limited knowledge.

I have a listview in my form1 called listMachine
And I have a method in form1.cs such as

```
private void máquinaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    machinename open = new machinename();
    open.Show();
}
```

machinename.cs is another form, and I use that method to open my other form, with an object called open.

the machinename button is a simple form which just serves as an input receiver, it asks a name, we have to type it into the textbox, press a button and it receives the input.

This is the code that runs when you press the button

```
public void buttonAceitarnome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBoxnomenova.TextLength == 0)
    {
        toolTipEmptyname.Show("O nome da máquina não pode estar vazio", textBoxnomenova);
    }
    else
    {
        Variables.var = textBoxnomenova.Text;
        //MessageBox.Show(Variables.var); debug purpose, the messagebox does carry variables.var text
        obj.listMachine.Items.Add(Variables.var);  //If I change the variables.var to "test" it will NOT add the item.
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, I forgot to mention my Variables.cs class, I created it because it was the only way I found to pass variables from a class to another (machinename.cs to form1.cs), but still, the items are not added into the listview.
This is my variables.cs code

```
public static class Variables
{
    public static string var;
}
```

The comments I added to the code also give you some extra debug info..
I didn't want to ask for online help, but couldn't solve this on my own :(

Comment: You can expose an internal property on the second form (assuming you dont want public but it probably doesn't matter) and access the other form that way as long as you have a reference to it from the original form.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean!

Comment: @1337patchy how did you know it's not added? By re-showing the form? Because I can see you call `this.Close()` after adding the item to your listview, that's strange.

Comment: I mean you can expose an internal \ public method on form2 and pass the data to it. This assumes that form1 created form2 and maintains a reference to it.

Comment: King King this.close is to close form2, I don't want it to be displayed anymore after pressing the button, the list is in form1.

Comment: Also Mike, could you explain how I can do it, I'm not following too well, my knowledge is very limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would first remove the `Variables` class.
Then, you'r first form/class is called `obj.cs`, am I right? Or is it `form1.cs`?

I made it look like this:

```
public partial class obj : Form
{
    public static string text; //This is a variable that can be reached from 

    public obj()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void máquinaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        machinename open = new machinename();
        open.ShowDialog(); //I put ShowDialog instead of Show
        addItem(); //This method is called when the showed dialog is closed (machinename.cs)
    }

    private void addItem()
    {
        listMachine.Items.Add(text);
    }
}
```

and the `machinename.cs` class like this:

```
public partial class machinename : Form
{
    public machinename()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonAceitarnome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //This one can be private
    {
        if (textBoxnomenova.TextLength == 0)
        {
            //Something here
        }
        else
        {
            obj.text = textBoxnomenova.Text; //Initializing the public static variable                
            this.Close(); //Closes the form, next step will be to run the method in obj.cs

        }
    }
}
```

If I understood your question correctly, you wanted to add an item to the ListView called "listMachine" via a button in the form "machinename.cs". This code will do that. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you zerato!! That fixed my issue and cooled my frustration! Thank you brother!

Answer (score 0):

Change the click event from private to protected.

```
protected void máquinaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```